# Why is the message not disappearing after two hours when connected to my countdown timer written in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, timing

*I want the Timer to display "Currently streaming" for two hours after the countdown ended, and then to start the next countdown. For some reason that just doesn't work/the text stays there forever/for way too long.*

```
// Stream slots in UTC (Germany is UTC+2)
const streamTimes = [
  { day: 1, hour: 17, minute: 0 },     // Monday
  { day: 2, hour: 17, minute: 0 },     // Tuesday
  { day: 3, hour: 17, minute: 0 },     // Wednesday
  { day: 4, hour: 17, minute: 0 },     // Thursday
  { day: 5, hour: 18, minute: 0 },     // Friday
  { day: 6, hour: 13, minute: 0 },     // Saturday
];

function getNextStreamTime() {
  const now = new Date();
  const currentDay = now.getUTCDay();
  const currentHour = now.getUTCHours();
  const currentMinute = now.getUTCMinutes();
  
  for (let i = 0; i < streamTimes.length; i++) {
    const streamTime = streamTimes[i];
    if (streamTime.day > currentDay || (streamTime.day === currentDay && streamTime.hour > currentHour) || (streamTime.day === currentDay && streamTime.hour === currentHour && streamTime.minute > currentMinute)) {
      return streamTime;
    }
  }

  // If there are no more stream slots, move on to monday
  return streamTimes[0];
}

function startCountdown() {
  const countdownElement = document.getElementById("countdown");
  
  const nextStreamTime = getNextStreamTime();
  const targetDate = new Date();
  targetDate.setUTCHours(nextStreamTime.hour, nextStreamTime.minute, 0, 0);
  
  const timer = setInterval(() => {
    const currentDate = new Date();
    const timeDifference = targetDate - currentDate;
    
    if (timeDifference <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timer);
      countdownElement.innerHTML = "Currently streaming";
      setTimeout(startCountdown, 2 * 60 * 60 * 1000); 
      return;
    }
    
    const days = Math.floor(timeDifference / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    const hours = Math.floor((timeDifference % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    const minutes = Math.floor((timeDifference % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    const seconds = Math.floor((timeDifference % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    
    countdownElement.innerHTML = `${days} days, ${hours} hours, ${minutes} minutes, ${seconds} seconds`;
  }, 1000);
}

startCountdown();
```

I expected it to work like that and have absolutely no idea why it isn't working.

Comment: Please note: The timezone Germany is in is not UTC. The Timezone for Berlin, Amsterdam etc. (*Central European Time*) is UTC+2 in summer and UTC+1 in winter.

Comment: Yes I know. The times are supposed to be 19:00, 20:00 and 15:00 so I just put them back 2 hours so that shouldn't be the Problem.

Comment: I would put a `console.log('currently streaming')` at the same location as your `innerHTML`,  check the console, I've a feeling your logic for `getNextStreamTime` is not correct, I would also put a `console.log(nextStreamTime)` in there as well for good measure.  What you might find is your will have multiple `currently streaming` in your log.

Comment: Note that if you unfocus the tab/window chrome will throttle setInterval. Firefox does not, at least not the last time I tested it (admittedly a few years ago). Not sure if that's your problem, but something to be aware of.

Answer (score 1):

So on day=1 you finish streaming at 19:00, then you set the target date to the same day, but at 17:00. Which means that `targetDate - currentDate` will be less than 0 because you haven't set targetDate to be the next day, therefore displaying `Currently streaming` and setting another timer for 2 hours. It isn't until the next day, that it will actually start working again. Replace:

```js
const targetDate = new Date(Date.now() + 864E5 * (nextStreamTime.day - new Date().getUTCDay()))
```

`864E5` is the number of milliseconds in a day, so you want to add that to the current date if the target date is tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

I copied your code and made some changes. First, there are a bunch of number calculations representing durations which are repeated multiple times and then re-calculated once a second.  These only need to be done once because these are fixed calculations.

I also noticed that you did not have Sunday in your list of days... but since you are looking the days up by the index number this should be fine. Just wanted to point that out in case it was overlooked.

I added a bunch of debug elements to show the output of the different variables. Honestly I'm not totally sure what your issue is, the code seems to work.  If I switch out the delay on the `setTimeout` for something like 5 seconds, the countdown updates. So that part of it seems to be working.  I hope maybe some of the output/debug elements can help you track it down.

```js
// Stream slots in UTC (Germany is UTC+2)
const streamTimes = [
  //{ day: 0, hour: 0, minute: 0 },     // Sunday
  { day: 1, hour: 17, minute: 0 },     // Monday
  { day: 2, hour: 17, minute: 0 },     // Tuesday
  { day: 3, hour: 17, minute: 0 },     // Wednesday
  { day: 4, hour: 17, minute: 0 },     // Thursday
  { day: 5, hour: 18, minute: 0 },     // Friday
  { day: 6, hour: 13, minute: 0 },     // Saturday
];

//Fixed time calculations
const oneSecondMs = 1000
const oneMinuteMs = oneSecondMs * 60;
const oneHourMs = oneMinuteMs * 60;
const oneDayMs = oneHourMs * 24;

function getNextStreamTime() {
  const now = new Date();
  const currentDay = now.getUTCDay();
  const currentHour = now.getUTCHours();
  const currentMinute = now.getUTCMinutes();
  
  for (let i = 0; i < streamTimes.length; i++) {
    const streamTime = streamTimes[i];
    if (streamTime.day > currentDay || (streamTime.day === currentDay && streamTime.hour > currentHour) || (streamTime.day === currentDay && streamTime.hour === currentHour && streamTime.minute > currentMinute)) {
      return streamTime;
    }
  }

  // If there are no more stream slots, move on to monday
  return streamTimes[0];
}

function getCountdownString(timeDifference){
  const days = Math.floor(timeDifference / oneDayMs);
  const hours = Math.floor((timeDifference % oneDayMs) / oneHourMs);
  const minutes = Math.floor((timeDifference % oneHourMs) / oneMinuteMs);
  const seconds = Math.floor((timeDifference % oneMinuteMs) / oneSecondMs);
    
  return `${days} days, ${hours} hours, ${minutes} minutes, ${seconds} seconds`;
}

function startCountdown() {
  const countdownElement = document.getElementById("countdown");
  
  const nextStreamTime = getNextStreamTime();
  const targetDate = new Date();
  targetDate.setUTCHours(nextStreamTime.hour, nextStreamTime.minute, 0, 0);
  
  document.getElementById("debugNextStreamTime").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(nextStreamTime, null, 2);
  document.getElementById("debugTargetDate").innerHTML = targetDate;
  
  const timer = setInterval(() => {
    const currentDate = new Date();
    const timeDifference = targetDate - currentDate;
    
    document.getElementById("debugCountdown").innerHTML = getCountdownString(timeDifference);
    
    if (timeDifference <= 0) {
      clearInterval(timer);
      countdownElement.innerHTML = "Currently streaming";
      setTimeout(startCountdown, oneHourMs*2); 
    } else {
      countdownElement.innerHTML = getCountdownString(timeDifference);
    }
  }, oneSecondMs);
}

startCountdown();
```

```css
pre {background:#eee; border:1px solid #ccc; padding:5px; margin:5px 0;}
```

```html
<h4>Output: <span id="countdown"></span></h4>

Next Stream Time
<pre id="debugNextStreamTime"></pre>

Target Date
<pre id="debugTargetDate"></pre>

Countdown
<pre id="debugCountdown"></pre>
```